# How can I get .Json dataset on a live ravendb server using fast-api?

Tags: python, json, database, fastapi, ravendb

I'm trying to create an endpoint to get a json dataset in the database "DSITE1" that i've stored in the live ravendb server "http://live-test.ravendb.net", but it's not working.

- I don't know if that's the proper Id to the json data,also when I store a json dataset in the live server it automatically creates its own id.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pyravendb.store import document_store

app = FastAPI()

document_store = document_store.DocumentStore(urls=["http://live-test.ravendb.net"], database="DSITE1")
document_store.initialize()
    
@app.get("/json_data/")
def json_data():
    with document_store.open_session() as session:
        data = session.load("dicts/1-A")  

    return data
```

Here's an example of original json data :

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Widget",
      "price": 10.99
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Gadget",
      "price": 24.95
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Doodad",
      "price": 5.99
    }
  ]
```

Here's the json data after storage in the database DSITE1 :

```
{
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Widget",
      "price": 10.99
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Gadget",
      "price": 24.95
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Doodad",
      "price": 5.99
    },
    "Id": "dicts/1-A",
    "@metadata": {
        "@collection": "dicts",
        "Raven-Python-Type": "builtins.dict"
    }
}
```

Here's how i've stored it in the live server :

```
from ravendb import DocumentStore
import json

document_store = DocumentStore(urls=["http://live-test.ravendb.net"], database="DSITE1")
document_store.initialize()

with open(path\site1.json", "r") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

with document_store.open_session() as session:
    for data in json_data:
        session.store(data)
    session.save_changes()

document_store.close()
```

Comment: If you want to **set the ID** that is given for the document when you 'store' then you can use: `session.store(data, "<someID>")`

Comment: You can also request the server to generate the document ID for you with the following options:

1. **Using a pipe** : ``session.store(data,"<collectionClassName>|">` the server will create an ID that is called an "identity". 

2. **Using a slash** :  `"session.store(data,"<collectionClassName"/>` the server will create an ID called "server-side ID".

3. The ID you received above "dicts/1-A"  comes from the "Hilo algorithm".

==> See all available ID generation methods in: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/6.0/csharp/server/kb/document-identifier-generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your RavenDB instance dont exist DSITE1 database.

[image]

But for example if u choose DBGZ database and one of products by ID it's working fine.

[image]

Code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pyravendb.store import document_store

app = FastAPI()

# select DBGZ DB for example
document_store = document_store.DocumentStore(urls=["http://live-test.ravendb.net"], database="DBGZ")
document_store.initialize()


@app.get("/json_data/")
def json_data():
    with document_store.open_session() as session:
        # select product by product ID
        data = session.load("products/77-A")

    return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=8080)
```

You can make the product id in [FastAPI path parameters](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#path-parameters).

For example:

```
@app.get("/json_data/{product_id}")
def json_data(product_id: str):
    print(product_id)
    with document_store.open_session() as session:
        # select product by product ID
        data = session.load(product_id)

    return data
```